# What is the most simple implementation of IDynamicMetaObjectProvider?

Tags: .net, serialization, dynamic, dynamic-language-runtime

I have this scenario...

1.- I'm providing a "Dynamic Table" for wich users can define Fields. Each Dynamic Table will have as many rows/records as needed, but the Field definitions are centralized.

2.- My Dynamic Row/Record class was inherited from the .NET DLR DynamicObject class, and the underlying storage was a List appropriately associated to the defining fields. Everything works fine! BUT...

3.- Because I need to Serialize the content, and DynamicObject is not Serializable, I was forced to generate and carry a Dynamic Object when dynamic member access is required. But this is ugly and redundant.

So, I need to implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider myself to achieve dynamic access and serialization together.

After googling/binging unsuccessfully I ask for your help...
Can anybody please give a good example (or related link) for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to implement Custom Serialization.
Implement the  ISerializable interface, plus the deserialization constructor.

It takes less time that implement IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you are re-inventing the [ExpandoObject class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).  Consider a collection of those for your implementation instead.

Comment: No. ExpandoObject is better for isolated objects because of no centralized fields definitions set. Plus, it is not Serializable.